# Why I get executions' time equal to zero?

Tags: python, function, time

I am writing a program in python and I want to calculate the execution time of more than one function in my program and I get the calculated time equal to 0.0!! why this is occurring, please? Note that I used more than one approach in calculation using time and DateTime modules and get the same results.
This is an example of my code :

```
import time
t1 = time.time()
keys = RSA.generateKey(K) # calling user define function 
t2 = time.time()
print(" key generat: ", t2 - t1)
```

output:

```
key generat:  0.0
```

Shouldn't there be a time difference even if it is very small?

Comment: `time.time()` is only accurate to the second. If it takes less than a second you'll get 0.

Answer (score 1):

Using datetime module you can calculate time taken to execute function.

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
# function()
t = datetime.now() - start
print(t)
```